# Timbersaw's Whirling Death and Timber Chain interaction

Tags: dota-2

I sometimes see Timbersaw doing Whirling Death right before Timber Chain started to move Timbersaw to a tree.

How does this mechanic work?

Does Whirling Death do damage in the area of the start point or in the entire path till the trees or even at the end too? This would maximize the AOE by a lot.

I myself played a lot of Timbersaw but always play it safe (no fun allowed). That's why i never used both spells in conjunction (i was not sure if i was wasting the nuke because i dont get the mechanics).

So can i increase the AOE by using Timber Chain with Whirling Death?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't increase the AOE. The AOE is 300 around the casting point and that's it.

I see 2 possible reasons why you witnessed someone using Whirling Death before Timber Chain :

- There were trees around and the enemy was in range so since a tree was cut, Whirling Death's damage became pure.
- It's a miss timing trying to Whirling Death while Timber Chaining(the timing to combo those spells is really hard to master). This just allows you to be more of a nuisance to your enemy. Whirling Death is a powerful nuke since it deals good damage, at low cooldown and reducing primary stats so when you have plenty of mana, why not use both ?

Comment: I must admit i thought being in Timber Chain i was unable to cast other spells. I probably did that in fights without knowing. I should revaluate my timbersaw replays

Answer (score 1):

Whirling death deals the full damage right after the spell is cast; the animation is nothing more than eye candy visuals. Therefore, whether you cast it before, during, or after timber chaining, the range stays the same: 300 AoE centered at the casting point.